# Groovy unsupported Target MODULE - build error

Tags: groovy

I updated a lib version and ran into this (below).

JDK 11.
Groovy 2.5.22
Gradle 7.6.1

I find references to similar errors 5 years go with Java 8 and Groovy 2.4, but nothing recent.   I checked the offending commit for the library, but nothing stands out.   Any ideas?

```
Caused by: BUG! exception in phase 'class generation' in source unit 'MyPrecious.groovy' unsupported Target MODULE
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.ApiGroovyCompiler.execute(ApiGroovyCompiler.java:271)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.ApiGroovyCompiler.execute(ApiGroovyCompiler.java:64)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.GroovyCompilerFactory$DaemonSideCompiler.execute(GroovyCompilerFactory.java:97)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.GroovyCompilerFactory$DaemonSideCompiler.execute(GroovyCompilerFactory.java:76)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.daemon.AbstractDaemonCompiler$CompilerWorkAction.execute(AbstractDaemonCompiler.java:135)
        at org.gradle.workers.internal.DefaultWorkerServer.execute(DefaultWorkerServer.java:63)
        at org.gradle.workers.internal.AbstractClassLoaderWorker$1.create(AbstractClassLoaderWorker.java:49)
        at org.gradle.workers.internal.AbstractClassLoaderWorker$1.create(AbstractClassLoaderWorker.java:43)
```